# 3-point counterterm in scalar QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, regularization

I'm working on the 1-loop corrections to scalar QED. I'm using dimensional regularization and on-shell regularization. In trying to compute the counterterm for the 3-point graph I come across the following integral:

$$e^3\int \Big[\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{(q_1^\mu+k^\mu)}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon}\times \frac{1}{(k-q_1)^2+i\epsilon}\times (2k^\rho+p^\rho)\times\frac{(q^2_\mu+p_\mu+k_\mu)}{(p+k)^2-m^2+i\epsilon}\Big].$$

This is associated to the graph

[image]

Using a Feynman parameter, we can simplify:

$$ = 2e^3\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\int_0^1 dxdydz\delta(x+y+z-1)\frac{(q_1+k)\cdot(q_2+p+k)(2k^\rho+p^\rho)}{[(k+yp-zq)^2-\Delta+i\epsilon]^3}$$

where here we have let $\Delta = -xyp^2+(1-z)^2m^2$.  Then, as is the standard procedure, we shift $k\rightarrow k-yp+zq_1$ to make the denominator $(k^2-\Delta)^3$. The numerator gets a bit complicated under this transformation, but we should be able to simplify it in such a way that we can easily use dimensional regularization, let $d =4-\epsilon$, and expand about $\epsilon =0$ to find the divergent part.

This calculation is very similar to that done in Chapter 17.2 of Schwartz's quantum field theory where he computes the anomalous magnetic moment. However, I can't use the same techniques used there to simplify the numerator here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I need this to determine the 3-vertex counterterm of scalar QED. Maybe there is a shortcut to computing this that doesn't involve such a messy calculation?

Comment: Appendices B.3.2 and B.3.4 in the book of Schwartz might be helpful.

Comment: @Hyperon Yes, that is usually what I apply towards the end of the calculation to extract the divergent part. But it has proven more difficult in this example.

Comment: For the divergent part, only terms $\sim \int d^d k k_\alpha k_\beta /(k^2-\Delta)^3 =\int d^dk g_{\alpha \beta} /(k^2 -\Delta)^2+ \, {\text  UV finite \, terms}$ contribute, which leads to a considerable simplification of the calculation. Alternatively one could use the heat-kernel expansion for a systematic determination of all one-loop divergences of this theory.

Comment: Sorry, $g_{\alpha \beta} \to g_{\alpha \beta}/d$.

Comment: @Hyperon Why is that? It seems like, by the formulas in the appendices, terms proportional to $\int d^dk k^2/(k^2-\Delta)^3$ would contribute as well.

Comment: Yes, that's true. My somewhat sloppy notation also includes them: $\int d^d k \, k_\alpha k_\beta g^{\alpha \beta} /(k^2-\Delta)^3 =\int d^d k \, k^2/(k^2-\Delta)^3$.

Comment: All right, I think I worked it out. I have one more question. Are there any other 1-loop corrections to the 3-point vertex in scalar QED?

Comment: The one-loop contribution to the one-particle-irreducible part of the three-point function  in scalar QED is just given by this diagram.

Comment: Cool, thank you!